# SQR: error while loading shared libraries: libpdf.so

Tags: linux, oracle, peoplesoft, sqr

I am trying to run SQR on my linux machine.
So i installed Peoplesoft tool and when i tried to exeute sqr engine it is failing.

I referred [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E80738_01/pt854pbh2/eng/pt/tsqr/task_CreatingandRunningaSampleSQRProgram-c07c44.html#topofpage) page

I didn't connect oracle database yet, but i wanted to check is sqr engine is  running.

so i tried executing

```
./sqr
```

inside

```
/APP_NAME/bin/sqr/ORA/bin/
```

Is this the right way of running sqr engine?

Answer (score 1):

The sqr engine is not a process that runs regularly.  It parses sqr programs and tries to execute them.  Try running an sqr program.